# golang idiomatic way to detect no such host error

Tags: go

I am using this but it doesn't feel right:

```
if err, ok := err.(net.Error); ok {
    var message string
    if err.Timeout() {
        message = "Timeout"
    } else if strings.HasSuffix(err.Error(), "no such host") {
        message = "No such host"
    }
}
```

Is there a more idiomatic way?

Answer (score 4):

**As Of Go 1.13:**
You can use [errors.As](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#As), OR [errors.Is](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#Is)

```
var dnsError *net.DNSError
if errors.As(err, &dnsError) {
    fmt.Println("DNS Error", dnsError)
}
```

**Original Answer:**

You can check DNS errors with this code. For example if **err** is our error:

```
if err, ok := err.(*url.Error); ok {
    if err, ok := err.Err.(*net.OpError); ok {
        if _, ok := err.Err.(*net.DNSError); ok {
            retry(r)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [DNSError](https://golang.org/src/net/net.go?s=16532:16823#L541) type instead of common `Error`.

```
err, ok := err.(net.DNSError)
```

Comment: Needs to be `err.(*net.DNSError)`.  The DNSError type is always returned by address (as one should usually do when storing an object in an interface), so the type assertion `err.(net.DNSError)` will always fail.

Comment: how did you figure that out? what is the process?

Comment: @RileyGuerin This might help `fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(err))`